# How to pass parameter for Scale when use Cast as numeric?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

when I run this query, it's ok:

```
select cast(round(sum(23.44324),2) as numeric(36,2))
```

But what I want to pass parameter to scale so that I can configure it (by user)

How can I use it like this:

```
declare @aaa int = 3
select cast(round(sum(23.44324),@aaa) as numeric(36,@aaa))
```

Please give me an idea to solve this problem.

I'm very appriciated for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't parameterize a type specification in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I would say don't bother with the cast to numeric, it is fairly pointless anyway, after the rounding any casting is just your formatting the output, and formatting should be done in the presentation layer.

If you really want your output to have the same precision as your round then just cast to `FLOAT`:

```
declare @aaa int = 3
select cast(round(sum(23.44324),@aaa) as float)
```

This will return `23.443`, which is the same as casting to `numeric(36, 3)` anyway.

---

**ADDENDUM**

As has been pointed out in a comment the above method will not add trailing 0s, so 36.400 would be shortened to 36.4 even with a precision of 3.

While I do not condone this, and still say formatting should be done in the presentation layer, you could create a function to format your number:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FormatNumber (@Input FLOAT, @Precision INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(36)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(36) = CAST(ROUND(@Input, @Precision) AS VARCHAR(36));
    IF (CHARINDEX('.', @Output) > 0)

        RETURN SUBSTRING(@Output + REPLICATE('0', @Precision), 1, CHARINDEX('.', @Output) + @Precision)

    RETURN @Output + '.' + REPLICATE('0', @Precision);
END
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87a39/3)**

Comment: hi GarethD, your help definately solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: But if it is '23.4', the result just is 23.4. What he wants is the same format (it should be 23.400). How can we do that?

Comment: hi @GarethD, with returns by varchar type, how can we sum or calculate later for columns that used this functions? (e.g. in c#, xtrareport). I tried to find out other solution by return dynamic type (e.g.: if Precision is 2, we will return numeric(36,2), if Precision is 3, we will return numeric(36,3)...). But it is impossible. Please help me if you have free time. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can't, and I don't see why you would want to, after you have rounded to the same precision casting to numeric is just chaning the format of the number, it won't change its value, and formatting should be done in the presentation layer. just return it to c# using only round, and format at the last possible moment.